# Unity: How to resize a whole 2D sprite scene to any screen resolution?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, screen-resolution

guys! We are developing a 2D game for desktop and mobile. It is grid-based although we decided not to use tilemaps and, instead, create our own grid by code, because we need to program different actions and interactions for each tile. The game UI is on a canvas and that part resizes as we expected. Also, everything already works quite well "functionality-wise" on both, mobile and desktop. The problem is that, as we made the main grid and objects as sprites, it works great on any 16:9 screen, but some of the screen space gets cut when it runs on any wider screen.

How can we resize the whole sprite scene depending on screen size? I guess it has more to do with the camera than with the actual objects but we don´t have a clear clue. We already looked into "pixel-perfect camera" and, although we haven´t dug too deeply into it, it looks like it´s aimed more towards preserving artwork at full resolution and not so much at what we need.

This one is from the PC where we are developing the game and where it looks as it should:[image]

And this one is from a PC with a wider screen (16:10) where the scene gets cropped from the sides (In the previous picture I marked in orange/yellow the columns that are lost in this one)
[image]

I guess there should be a way to stretch all sprites to fit the screen, but I think the best way to go would be to get empty horizontal or vertical bars, on top and bottom or to the sides, in order to preserve the exact proportions, and that would be good enough. But how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! Starting with the great ideas **ephb** gave me, I finally decided to get a reference percentage between the screen width and height. So, for 1920x1080, which is the resolution I know the game looks correct in, I did a rule of three and got that 1080 is 56.25% of the screen width, and, that in that case, the camera size should be 5.

Knowing those two elements, now I can check the height proportion for the user´s device and, using another rule of three, calculate the correct camera size, like this:

```
Camera cam;
void Awake()
{
    cam = Camera.main;
    cam.orthographicSize = GetHeightProportion() * 5 / 56.25f; //1920x1080 reference ---
}

float GetHeightProportion()
{
    return ((float)Screen.height * 100) / (float)Screen.width;
}
```

Comment: Great that helped you. You can now also use similar ideas to calculate the size of some filler background element.

Comment: Thanks, ephb. You´ve been of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to resize fore any aspect ration not screen resolution. You use the aspect ratio dropdown of the [game window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GameView.html) to see how it looks without running it on different computers.

The default setting is that the **vertical** field of view of your camera stays the same. Since the 16:10 display is taller this results in your image appearing zoomed with the sides being cut off.

Since you are using sprites and you basically have to recreate what the canvas scaler does but in world space.

You could move your camera, change its FOV if it a perspective camera, change its size if it is an orthographic camera or scale your scene. I will describe the first steps.

1. Get [Screen](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html) width and height and calculate the aspect ratio.
2. Compare against your target aspect ratio. (I assume it is 16/9)
3. Use this multiplier to scale your scene / move your camera / change it's field of view

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is aspect ratio. Thanks a lot. Let me do some tests.